# How do I pass usernames from the User model in django to autocomplete

Tags: javascript, django, autocomplete

I am implementing autocomplete on a html page on my django website.

I am looking to use the autocomplete from materialize

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Materialize shows how data can be passed to this autocomplete

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, options);
  });


  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
    });
  });
```

I understand the second part and can implement it. However I do not understand how the first part works, which I think is what I will need.

My need is to pass the usernames from the User model in django to this autocomplete. How would I go about doing this

Comment: user types in input box -> make api call with input to get usernames -> update autocomplete with response from api call

Comment: What I don’t understand how to do is how I update autocomplete with the users . Not how to get the usernames in a list .

Comment: You have to take value of the input then make an api call and pass it that value. When that endpoint is hit you have to query database for usernames based on the input, then return results back to client

Answer (score 0):

You would pass the usernames into the context like this:

**view**

```
class YourView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'yourpage.html', {"users": User.objects.all()}
```

**html** (cannot be in .js file, since django needs to parse the file)

```
  var usernames = {
    {% for user in users %}
        {{ user.username }}: "{{ user.username }}",
    {% endfor %}
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: usernames,
    });
  });
```